# Calculating product rating

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image: A new value should be added as productRating under the product node]I am trying to calculate the product rating for my products in my realtime database using a firebase cloud function. What am I missing since am getting errors in the logs after deploying

I have deployed the code but still on rating added no change happens

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');

    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

    //firebase db calculations for rating average
    exports.productAverage = functions.database.ref('/Products/{product_id}/rating')
        .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
            return admin.database().ref('/Products/{product_id}/rating').once('value')
                .then((snapshot) => {
                    let sum = 0;
                    snapshot.forEach(child => {
                        sum = sum + child.val();
                    });
                    let productRating = sum / snapshot.numChildren();

                    return admin.database().ref('/Products/{product_id}').child('productRating').set(productRating);
                });
        });
```

I expect each time a productRating node is added, the average updates a node on the database with productRating

Comment: "I am getting errors in the logs after deploying"  Please edit your question to include the exact error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that immediately jump out:

1. You're triggering on `onCreate`. But you want to recalculate the average whenever any rating is added (or removed or updated), you'll want to trigger on `onWrite`.
2. You're reloading the same data in your function that is pass in already. That is wasteful, so let's remove that.

With these two changes, you'd end up with something like:

```
exports.productAverage = functions.database.ref('/Products/{product_id}/rating')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        let snapshot = change.after;

        let sum = 0;
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
            sum = sum + child.val();
        });
        let productRating = sum / snapshot.numChildren();

        return snapshot.ref.parent.child('productRating').set(productRating);
    });
```